# iOS Audio/Video Conference using open fire server

Tags: ios, xmpp, webrtc, openfire

I have successfully implemented one-one chat, group creation and group chat using XMPP framework in iOS and open fire server. Now i want implement audio and video chat using open fire server, but i don't have any solution how to proceed. For Android there is an excellent open source library named "JitSi", but there no support for iOS.

I have tried AppRTC demo. In that video chat is happening through their own server not using XMPP server.

There are some third party sdk's like opentok which are providing same features, but i don't want to use them.

Please help me out on this.

Comment: Have you got any solution. If please share.

Comment: Jitsi now supports both android and iOS